# how can I send request body parameter through put Method with swagger-client

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I'm using swagger-client. that's a npm library module for client.
but I have a problem.
in Server side, I'm using express.

even If I try to send body parameter with put method, express doesn't take parameters.
only path param or query param can be reached.
those are no problem.

here is code and swagger json.

■ request path in json.

```
"/test/{hogehoge}/sample": {
      "put": {
        "summary": "summary",
        "description": "description",
        "tags": [
          "Sample"
        ],
        "operationId": "operationId",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "path",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "path description",
            "required": true,
            "type": "integer"
          },
          {
            "name": "body",
            "in": "body",
            "description": "body",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/bodySchema"
            }
          }
        ],
```

■ request path schema to put method above.

```
"bodySchema": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "bodySchemaVersion": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "bodySchema version"
        }
      }
    },
```

■ express logs

```
parameter:
 { query: {},
path:
{ param1: 'param1',
param2: 'param2' },
body: {} } } ← body that it should be bodySchema param.
```

■client side vue

```
import Swagger from 'swagger-client';
import swaggerJson from '@/assets/swagger/swagger.json';

....

// opts include 
// { bodySchema: { bodySchemaVersion: 'string text' } }


await this.swagger.client.apis[tagName][funcName](_opts);
```

Comment: Does your Swagger JSON file specify `"consumes": ["application/json"]` either for that request or globally?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem.

```
this.swagger = new Swagger({
  spec: json,
  usePromise: true,
  requestInterceptor(req) {
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'; // I've add this line.
    return req
  }
});
```